# MVC Helpers Working inline, but not in App_Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Originally I repeated lines of code for each menu item and just hard coded the various menu item values but then I came across helpers and taught I would give it a try. Now 6 lines of code (for each menu item) are reduced to one (for each item), and I have a single place to go to alter anything instead of changing it in 5 places. All great stuff. Here is the code:

```
@helper MenuItem(string action, string controller)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action(action, controller)" id="@controller">
        <div class="MenuItem">
            <img src="@("/XXX.YYY.Web/Content/Images/Icons/Menu/mnu"+controller+".png")" /><br />
            //I had to put the XXX.YYY as a literal string because the ~ didn't work, it was quoted literally also instead of showing the home folder.
            @controller
        </div>
    </a>
}
```

My problem is that it works when I use it inline, say at the top of my _Layout.cshtml with the following lines of code:

```
        @MenuItem("Index", "Home")
        @MenuItem("Index", "Chart")
```

But when I remove it out to a generic helper called LayoutHelpers.cshtml under the App_Code folder so I can reuse it, and alter the code accordingly as follows:

```
        @LayoutHelpers.MenuItem("Index", "Home")
        @LayoutHelpers.MenuItem("Index", "Chart")
```

Note: Nothing in the actual helper changed. Only the above 2 lines in the _Layout.cshtml file changed.

When I make those changes I get the following error:

Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Line 3:  @helper MenuItem(string action, string controller)
Line 4:  {
Line 5:      
Line 6:          
Line 7:              @
@

Now the curious thing is, notice how it works on line 7 "mnuHome.png" as opposed to mnucontroller.png. Yet it says that line 5 is in error.

I also have a problem with the ~ not working in the helper. ie. the ~/Content is shown as a literal string instead of it being compiled to a proper path which should always point to the home folder of the app.

Following is a link that I am using for reference:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/03/23/comparing-mvc-3-helpers-using-extension-methods-and-declarative-razor-helper.aspx

Specifically less than 1/4 of the way down the page under the heading "Razor Declarative Helpers". From here on.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard helpers (such as UrlHelper and HtmlHelper) are not available in a Razor inline `@helper`. If you need to use it will need to pass the UrlHelper as parameter to your helper:

```
@helper MenuItem(UrlHelper url, string action, string controller)
{
    <a href="@url.Action(action, controller)" id="@controller">
        <div class="MenuItem">
            <img src="@url.Content("~/XXX.YYY.Web/Content/Images/Icons/Menu/mnu"+controller+".png")" />
            <br />
            @controller
        </div>
    </a>
}
```

and then when calling pass the correct instance:

```
@LayoutHelpers.MenuItem(Url, "Index", "Home")
@LayoutHelpers.MenuItem(Url, "Index", "Chart")
```

Comment: +1 so far as this worked. I will be accepting this as the answer. But for extra brownie points, can you suggest a way I can fix the problem with this "~" not resolving to the home folder the way it normally should. I would prefer to use "~" instead of specifying the home folder because it will change when it goes on the server and then the images wont work.

Comment: Well, use the `UrlHelper`, that's what it is designed for. I have updated my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: +1 again on the comments, Brilliant, This worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you give us a quick example if I wanted to use a HtmlHelper say like @{HtmlRenderAction("SomeAction");} inside of a helper, how would I pass it in. Perhaps even as an extended edit on your answer. I will of course vote your comment up again.

Comment: The same way you did with the UrlHelper => you pass it as argument: `@helper FooBar(HtmlHelper html)` and then simply `html.RenderAction("SomeAction")`.

Comment: Hi Darin, as promised, I came back today and added a different question. here is the link to it encase you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810771/mvc4-urlhelper-working-but-htmlhelper-is-not-what-am-i-doing-wrong Thanks again.